# MediaWiki {{PAGENAME}} includes namespace

Tags: namespaces, mediawiki

I have a page titled "Commands:afk".

Now when I use {{PAGENAME}} on the site, it always returns "Commands:afk".
However as written in the documentation at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Page_names, pagename should **not** include the namespace (which is supposed to be included only in {{FULLPAGENAME}}).
I want to get only the "afk" part of the pagename.

Am I perhaps doing something wrong or could this be a bug?
I couldn't find any information at all about this on the web.
I am using latest stable of MediaWiki.

Comment: Are you sure you have a namespace called `Commands`, or do you just have a page called `Commands:afk`?

Comment: Even if there is such a namespace, there could still be a page which is called `Commands:afk` and is in the main namespace. This can happen due to bugs and is very rare but not impossible.

Comment: This seems to be it.
I didn't know you had to manually create the namespaces in the config.
MediaWiki is really some weird construct (and by no means in any good way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments and in https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Using_custom_namespaces , you have to set `$wgExtraNamespaces` and run `maintenance/namespaceDupes.php`.